# Type Error-String indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

I am getting type error while iterating over the Dictionary. Type Error-String indices must be integers

```
data = {"GetEventHeadlines_Response_1":{"EventHeadlines":{"Headline":[{"CountryCode":"US","EventType":"EarningsCallsAndPresentations","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"None","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"EventId":12969284,"LastUpdate":"2020-01-02T19:06:09.267","LiveDialIn":{"Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"None","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"Password":"6378226","PhoneNumber":"+1-845-675-0437","Status":"Available"},"LiveWebcast":{"Type":"ThirdParty","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T14:00:00","EndQualifier":"DateTime","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"WebcastId":"840B9947-C69D-40E5-AF4F-4F35B1FF069C","Provider":"WindowsMedia","Url":null},"Name":"Q3 2019 Nio Inc Earnings Call","ReplayDialIn":{"Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2020-01-07T12:59:00","EndQualifier":"DateTime","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T15:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"Password":"6378226","PhoneNumber":"+1-646-254-3697","Status":"Available"},"ReplayWebcast":{"Type":"ThirdParty","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2020-01-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"DateOnly","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T14:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"WebcastId":"0816103B-4559-4816-BE2A-BC1B5612486B","Provider":"WindowsMedia","Url":null},"Transcript":{"Status":"Final","TranscriptId":"8874A5B3-06BC-4863-9890-9F6775E1A219","DeliveryType":"Live","Locale":"en-US"},"Organization":{"Name":"Nio Inc","Symbols":{"Symbol":[{"Type":"RIC","Value":"NIO.N"}]}},"RsvpRequired":false}]},"PaginationResult":{"PageNumber":1,"RecordsOnPage":1,"RecordsPerPage":100,"TotalRecords":1}}}

Doc_details= dict()

 for item in data['GetEventHeadlines_Response_1']['EventHeadlines']['Headline']:
 name= item['Name']
 docid=item['Transcript']['TranscriptId']
 Doc_details[name]=docid
print(Doc_details)

for key, value in Doc_details.items():
 print(key,value)
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-4ad75716058a> in <module>()
  1 Doc_details= {}
  2 
----> 3 for item in data['GetEventHeadlines_Response_1']['EventHeadlines']['Headline']:
  4     name= item['Name']
  5     docid=item['Transcript']['TranscriptId']

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: This code has obvious errors, and cannot run as shown.  Please update the question to contain your actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your `false` with `False` and it will work.
I have used another method of doing it, which takes this as a raw string and then converting it to JSON. In this way, the actual boolean values of JSON will be converted to Python way.

```
import json
data = r'''{"GetEventHeadlines_Response_1":{"EventHeadlines":{"Headline":[{"CountryCode":"US","EventType":"EarningsCallsAndPresentations","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"None","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"EventId":12969284,"LastUpdate":"2020-01-02T19:06:09.267","LiveDialIn":{"Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"None","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"Password":"6378226","PhoneNumber":"+1-845-675-0437","Status":"Available"},"LiveWebcast":{"Type":"ThirdParty","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T14:00:00","EndQualifier":"DateTime","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"WebcastId":"840B9947-C69D-40E5-AF4F-4F35B1FF069C","Provider":"WindowsMedia","Url":null},"Name":"Q3 2019 Nio Inc Earnings Call","ReplayDialIn":{"Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2020-01-07T12:59:00","EndQualifier":"DateTime","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T15:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"Password":"6378226","PhoneNumber":"+1-646-254-3697","Status":"Available"},"ReplayWebcast":{"Type":"ThirdParty","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2020-01-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"DateOnly","IsEstimate":false,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T14:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"WebcastId":"0816103B-4559-4816-BE2A-BC1B5612486B","Provider":"WindowsMedia","Url":null},"Transcript":{"Status":"Final","TranscriptId":"8874A5B3-06BC-4863-9890-9F6775E1A219","DeliveryType":"Live","Locale":"en-US"},"Organization":{"Name":"Nio Inc","Symbols":{"Symbol":[{"Type":"RIC","Value":"NIO.N"}]}},"RsvpRequired":false}]},"PaginationResult":{"PageNumber":1,"RecordsOnPage":1,"RecordsPerPage":100,"TotalRecords":1}}}'''
data = json.loads(data)

Doc_details= dict()

for item in data['GetEventHeadlines_Response_1']['EventHeadlines']['Headline']:
    name= item['Name']
    docid=item['Transcript']['TranscriptId']
    Doc_details[name]=docid

print(Doc_details)

for key, value in Doc_details.items():
    print(key,value)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav for your answer. It works really well. What if i import my data from local. How can i format this? I have saved data.json in my working directory. How will this work?

Comment: Just import your data from file, put that in a string 'data' and rest of the code will remain same.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried copying the code here and testing it and I didn't get the error.
I did edit a couple of values e.g. false to False but that's about it.
The result I got was as follows:

{'Q3 2019 Nio Inc Earnings Call': '8874A5B3-06BC-4863-9890-9F6775E1A219'}

Q3 2019 Nio Inc Earnings Call 8874A5B3-06BC-4863-9890-9F6775E1A219

Here is the code in case I have copied it incorrectly.

```py
data = {"GetEventHeadlines_Response_1":{"EventHeadlines":{"Headline":[{"CountryCode":"US","EventType":"EarningsCallsAndPresentations","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"None","IsEstimate":False,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"EventId":12969284,"LastUpdate":"2020-01-02T19:06:09.267","LiveDialIn":{"Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"None","IsEstimate":False,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"Password":"6378226","PhoneNumber":"+1-845-675-0437","Status":"Available"},"LiveWebcast":{"Type":"ThirdParty","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2019-12-30T14:00:00","EndQualifier":"DateTime","IsEstimate":False,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T12:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"WebcastId":"840B9947-C69D-40E5-AF4F-4F35B1FF069C","Provider":"WindowsMedia"},"Name":"Q3 2019 Nio Inc Earnings Call","ReplayDialIn":{"Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2020-01-07T12:59:00","EndQualifier":"DateTime","IsEstimate":False,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T15:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"Password":"6378226","PhoneNumber":"+1-646-254-3697","Status":"Available"},"ReplayWebcast":{"Type":"ThirdParty","Duration":{"EndDateTime":"2020-01-30T12:00:00","EndQualifier":"DateOnly","IsEstimate":False,"StartDateTime":"2019-12-30T14:00:00","StartQualifier":"DateTime"},"WebcastId":"0816103B-4559-4816-BE2A-BC1B5612486B","Provider":"WindowsMedia"},"Transcript":{"Status":"Final","TranscriptId":"8874A5B3-06BC-4863-9890-9F6775E1A219","DeliveryType":"Live","Locale":"en-US"},"Organization":{"Name":"Nio Inc","Symbols":{"Symbol":[{"Type":"RIC","Value":"NIO.N"}]}},"RsvpRequired":False}]},"PaginationResult":{"PageNumber":1,"RecordsOnPage":1,"RecordsPerPage":100,"TotalRecords":1}}} 

Doc_details= {}

for item in data['GetEventHeadlines_Response_1']['EventHeadlines']['Headline']:
    name= item['Name']
    docid=item['Transcript']['TranscriptId']
    Doc_details[name]=docid
print(Doc_details)

for key, value in Doc_details.items():
    print(key,value)
```

Comment: It works really well. What if i import my data from local. How can i format this? I have saved data.json in my working directory. How will this work?

Comment: You could try using open and json.loads e.g.                                                      
with open('data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

Comment: with open('quoteResult.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
Doc_details= dict()

for item in data['GetEventHeadlines_Response_1']['EventHeadlines']['Headline']:
    name= item['Name']
    docid=item['Transcript']['TranscriptId']
    Doc_details[name]=docid      #This is also give the same type error. I guess i need to change false first

Comment: Yes sorry I should have said. You will need to change the false to False in order for it to be recognised as a boolean value.